# Can I autowire a Spring bean into a MapStruct interface?

Tags: java, spring-boot, mapstruct

I am using `MapStruct` and to do that I have to define an interface with an according mapping function. It is possible to implement some logic by using a `default` method annotated with **`@BeforeMapping`** and **@AfterMapping**. In such an annotated default method I want to use a configuration class of my SpringBoot application. How can I do this? Can I autowire such a configuration (bean) into an interface? How should such a code look like?

---

From the documentation and your hint I found out that I can use either a @Context variable or an abstract class instead of using an interface.

I tried both then. Using an abstract class it worked well as demanded but using a @Context variable the default method gets not invoked.

Here's the main mapping method:

```java
@Mapping(target = "myTarget.partNumber", ignore = true)
public MyTarget mapSource2Target(final MySource mySource, final PartNumberMapConfiguration partNumberMapConfiguration);
```

and the *afterMapping* method:

```java
@AfterMapping
default void afterMapping(final @MappingTarget MyTarget target, final MySource source, final @Context PartNumberMapConfiguration partNumberMapConfiguration) {. . . }
```

When I reach the breakpoint where the mapper is invoked, I cannot step into the mapping method. It just steps over...and the code of the afterMapping method is not executed.

Here's the class I intend to use as with @Context:

```java
@Component("PartNumberMap")
@PropertySource("classpath:abc.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "abc")
public class PartNumberMapConfiguration {
    
    private Map<String, String> partNumberMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    
    public Map<String, String> getPartNumberMap() {
        return partNumberMap;
    }
    
    public void setPartNumberMap(final Map<String, String> partNumberMap) {
        this.partNumberMap = partNumberMap;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't autowire a bean into an interface. However, you can use the `@Context` from MapStruct 1.2.0.

For example:

```
@Mapper
public interface MyMapper {

    Target map(Source source, @Context MyCustomService service);

    @AfterMapping
    default void after(Source source, @MappingTarget Target target, @Context MyCustomService service) {
        // Your logic
    }
}
```

Another option would be to use an abstract class instead of an interface.

```
@Mapper
public abstract class MyMapper {

    private MyCustomService service;

    public abstract Target map(Source source);


    @AfterMapping
    protected after(Source source, @MappingTarget Target target) {
        // Use the service here
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setService(MyCustomService service) {
        this.service = service.
    }    
}
```

Comment: You used a service to be autowired or as a context respectively. Can it be a Configuration class as well??

Comment: The context. Can be anything. You are the one passing it in thr map method. As for autowiring it can be any Spring bean

Comment: public abstract MyTarget mySourceToMyTarget(final Issue issue, final MyConfiguration myConfiguration);

(at)AfterMapping
default void afterMapping(final (at)MappingTarget MyTarget target, final Issue source, final (at)Context MyConfiguration myConfiguration) {
. . .  <br/>
The AfterMapping method is **not** invoked using an interface. Using abstract class it works well. 
This is the configuration file:
(at)Component("PartNumberMap")
(at)PropertySource("classpath:abc.properties")
(at)ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "abc")
public class PartNumberMapConfiguration {

Comment: Can you please update your question as having this in a comment is not clear at all

Comment: `@AfterMapping` method is not invoked using an interface or `@Context` is not supported in `@AfterMapping` methods.